# nodejs (mssql) error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, conversión-de-tipos, mssql

estoy programando una web con nodejs y mssql para usar sql server en base de datos, pero al ejecutar un procedimiento que retorna una fecha en formato string me salta el siguiente error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

la fecha está en formato 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' pero me salta ese error, he intentado poner algo tal que así:

```
let login = async(user, password) => {
    await sql.connect(config);
    let db = new sql.Request(); 
    db.input('email', sql.VarChar(100), user);
    db.input('PASS', sql.VarChar(250), password); 

    db.output('fecha_1', sql.VarChar(100));
    db.output('fecha_2', sql.VarChar(100));
    let result = await db.execute('login_usuario');

    return result.recordset;
};
```

pero al poner los output me salta el siguiente error:

```
Procedure or function login_usuario has too many arguments specified.
```

y no logro solucionar el primer error, ¿Alguien sabe que está mal?, No logro solucionarlo, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías poner el código del procedimiento, que es donde falla primero

Comment: Es que el procedimiento funciona bien, en Android e IOS sale bien el resultado, pero a mi con node me salta el error

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a la configuración del idioma en la base de datos. El formato en inglés es `mm/dd/yyyy` y en otros idiomas `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Hola Raphael. Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para explicar el fallo, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Trata de añadir algo más de información para completar la respuesta: ¿Cómo se haría lo que indicas? ¿cuál sería el código? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así también ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).